# Numpy taking only first character of string

Tags: python, numpy

Following is the simplified version of my problem. I want to create a `(N, 1)` shape numpy array, which would have strings as their values. However, when I try to insert the string, only the first character of the string gets inserted.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> N = 23000
>>> Y = np.empty((N, 1), dtype=str)
>>> Y.shape
(23000, 1)
>>> for i in range(N):
...     Y[i] = "random string"
...
>>> Y[10]
array(['r'], dtype='<U1')
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default data type `str` takes length of `1`. So, you will only get one character. we can set max data length by using `np.dtype('U100')`. `Un` where `U` is unicode and `n` is number of characters in it.

Try below code

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> N = 23000
>>> Y = np.empty((N, 1), dtype=np.dtype('U100'))
>>> Y.shape
(23000, 1)
>>> for i in range(N):
...     Y[i] = "random string"
...
>>> Y[10]
array(['random string'], dtype='<U100')
```

Answer (score 4):

Even though you specify `dtype=str` in `np.empty`, when you check Y, it isn't string type.

```
import numpy as np
N = 23000
Y = np.empty((N, 1), dtype=str)
Y
```

Output:

```
array([[''],
       [''],
       [''],
       ...,
       [''],
       [''],
       ['']], dtype='<U1')
```

The dtype is "U1".

This means, its a unicode string of length 1.

You can change it to

```
Y = np.empty((N, 1), dtype='U25')
```

Output for `Y[10]`:

```
array(['random string'], dtype='<U25')
```

I have given a random value as 25 for "U25". You can give any number there. 25 over here.

25 in U25 means unicode string of length 25