# Why is facecolor argument in plot_surface of matplotlib not working in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want my python code to generate a plot with alternating colors. For the sake of the problem, the alternating colors are irrelevant so let's say they're red and blue.
I'm creating a numpy array of the alternating colors with the same shape as the inputs x, y and z (251, 251)

```
colortuple = ('red', 'blue')
colors = np.array(
    [np.array([colortuple[int((xn + yn) % len(colortuple))] for xn in range(xrange)]) for yn in range(trange)])
```

The array prints the following to the console:

```
[['red' 'blue' 'red' ... 'red' 'blue' 'red']
 ['blue' 'red' 'blue' ... 'blue' 'red' 'blue']
 ['red' 'blue' 'red' ... 'red' 'blue' 'red']
 ...
 ['red' 'blue' 'red' ... 'red' 'blue' 'red']
 ['blue' 'red' 'blue' ... 'blue' 'red' 'blue']
 ['red' 'blue' 'red' ... 'red' 'blue' 'red']]
```

which is what I want.

However, when I pass it to plot_surface() as the facecolors argument

```
axes.plot_surface(X=x, Y=y, Z=z, facecolors=colors, linewidth=0)
```

the plot displayed only has the color of the first argument in colortuple, in this case red.
[image: The plot I'm creating which is fully red instead of having alternating colors]

All 4 variables {x, y, z, colors} have the same (251, 251) shape and are all numpy arrays.
I motivated my code from the following website:
https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html

The problem is similar to
[facecolors in plot_surface matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64607336/facecolors-in-plot-surface-matplotlib)
however I don't get any errors in the console, just a faulty execution.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think what you need is a colormap.  See this example : https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/mpl_examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.py

Comment: @AhmadAnis This is another example. The example I was trying to reproduce with different variables is https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/mpl_examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo3.py and this one doesn't use a colormap.

Comment: Instead of blue and red, try with 'b' and 'r'

Comment: @AhmadAnis That won't change anything about the plot.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

`facecolors` must be RGB or RGBA, it's simpler to use a 2-entries colormap.

```
from numpy import arange, cos, linspace, meshgrid, sin
from matplotlib import colors, pyplot
N = 32
x = linspace(0, 6.28, N)
X, Y = meshgrid(x, x)
Z = 2*sin(X)+cos(Y/2)
checkers = (arange((N-1)**2)%2).reshape((N-1,N-1))
# if (N-1) is odd, columns are already alternating, otherwise flip odd rows
if N%2: checkers[arange(1, N, 2)] = 1 - checkers[arange(1, N, 2)]
RB = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('RB', ['red', 'blue'], N=2)
facecolors = RB(checkers)
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, facecolors=facecolors)
pyplot.show()
```

---

The example above was constructed on a square grid, it's interesting to see what happens if we use a grid with a different number of subdivision on the x and y axes, `Nx` and `Ny`.

If `Nx` is odd, we need to alter the dimensions of our grid of `0`s and `1`s.

```
       0    1    2    3            The number of cells is one less
  6 +----+----+----+----+          than the number of grid points.
    |    |    |    |    | 5
  5 +----+----+----+----+          Here Nx = 5 (odd) and cNx = 4 (even),
    |    |    |    |    | 4        so in the following code we introduce
  4 +----+----+----+----+          an extra cell to have an odd number
    |    |    |    |    | 3        of cells.
  3 +----+----+----+----+
    |    |    |    |    | 2        Having one extra column is not a problem
  2 +----+----+----+----+          because the last column (in this case)
    |    |    |    |    | 1        is not used by Matplotlib.
  1 +----+----+----+----+
    |    |    |    |    | 0
  0 +----+----+----+----+
    0    1    2    3    4
```

[image]

```
from numpy import arange, cos, linspace, meshgrid, sin
from matplotlib import cm, colors, pyplot

def f(ax, Nx, Ny, c1, c2):

    x, y = linspace(0, 6.28, Nx), linspace(0, 6.28, Ny)
    X, Y = meshgrid(x, y)
    Z = 2*sin(X)+cos(Y/2)

    ax.set_title('$N_x=%d, N_y=%d.$'%(Nx, Ny))
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.set_zlabel('z')
    Nx = Nx+1 if Nx%2 else Nx
    c1c2 = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('RB', [c1, c2], N=2)
    checkers = c1c2((arange((Nx-1)*(Ny-1))%2).reshape((Ny-1, Nx-1)))
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, facecolors=checkers, shade=0)
    ax.azim, ax.elev = 80, 60 


fig, ((ax1, ax2),(ax3,ax4)) = pyplot.subplots(
    2, 2, layout='constrained', subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})

f(ax1, 7, 11, 'red', 'blue'), f(ax2, 7, 12, 'red', 'blue')
f(ax3, 8, 12, 'red', 'blue'), f(ax4, 8, 13, 'red', 'blue')

pyplot.show()
```